# TheActionBar disappear over the display when the keyboard appear

Tags: android, keyboard, android-actionbar

I ve an application that has a chat layout (a ScrollView hosting textviews at the top, an editText at the bottom and a button at the bottom)
When someone have to write something the keyboard appears and the entire screen scrollup (using adjustPan). The problem is that also the Action Bar srolls up and I want to avoid it how can I do??

Comment: is it happening in potrait or landscape mode if its in landscape mode then i doubt there is anything more you can do

Comment: post the xml of your editext